# Need help centering social media icons in the a footer on a website

Tags: html, css

I have been stuck on something very simple for over a day now and I have to ask for help.  I am trying to do something simple as centering vertically my social media icons in my footer.  I tried to take the same route when someone helped me with the Navigation Bar but I just cannot seem to grasp/understand something to get the same result.

I thought about doing padding but I was not sure if that still would take care of re-sizing or smaller screens, so I wanted to take more a percent route instead of flat amount.

[Website for Inspect](http://www.appsolutedevelopment.com/)

Footer HTML:

```
<!-- Social Media + Footer -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <img src="link/ico-facebook.png"
                                 alt="Facebook Icon"
                                 style="width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 32px">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="link/ico-twitter.png"
                                 alt="Twitter Icon"
                                 style="width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 32px">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Social Media + Footer -->
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.navbar-fixed-bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-width: 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block!important;
    height: auto!important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible!important;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) .navbar-collapse {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navbar-collapse {
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow-x: visible;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

.collapse {
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px).navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin: 7.5px -15px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px).navbar-nav>li {
    display: inline-block!important;
}

.nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block!important;
}

img.element.style {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 32px;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by apply some custom CSS to your HTML elements:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom" style="display: table !important; width: 100%;">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="vertical-align: middle;display: table-cell !important;">
  ......
  ......
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mary Melody for that.  It works just like I wanted it too.  I was so obsessed with putting everything in CSS that I overwhelmed myself when I could of just did custom CSS.  I should be doing both as I am learning.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I was the one who answered you the first time, so here I go again to make sure you understand how it works.

First, let's do a tiny change in your HTML markup, as follows:

```
<!-- Social Media + Footer -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse vertimid">            
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <img src="link/ico-facebook.png"
                                 alt="Facebook Icon"
                                 style="width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 32px">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="link/ico-twitter.png"
                                 alt="Twitter Icon"
                                 style="width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 32px">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Social Media + Footer -->
```

If you pay attention, I have only added the class `.vertimid` to the line

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
```

we do this in order to accurately target that class so you can re-use it later, as I told you the other day.

Now, you do add this property to

```
.navbar-collapse.vertimid{display:inline-block} /* replaces display:table */
```

and that's it.

Remember: you need to vertical align elements relative to the container block. Also, as we're at it, be sure to check your site in Firefox, because you'll find out your social media icons aren't there

Comment: No Mary, you can't use @media rules inline, only as part of a style sheet or inside the `<head>`. This is because of the CSS Syntax that forbids curly brackets, see [link]http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/#syntax for more information

Comment: Thank you once again @Fabio, just from that clarification again I think I am starting to understand where I was failing.  I am now starting to grasp the "display" property which I was lacking.  

Tell me if I am correct, display plays an important part for the actual positions of the elements inside?  Such as orientation, type of display structure and horizontal+vertical positioning?

Comment: @Fabio Thanks for helping! I didn't find anything about it. :)

Comment: yes indeed. Once you get the grasp of the display and position properties, CSS is quite easy

Comment: Awesome, you are amazing Fabio!  You are correct now that I am starting to grasp that after yours and @MaryMelody examples.

Answer (score 1):

Decide what height percentage of the footer you want your social media icons to be...suppose 30%:

```
ul.nav {
    height:30%;
    margin-top:35%;
    margin-bottom:35%;    
}
```